# can I develop qr-code based application for android and for iphone using appcelerator

Tags: iphone, appcelerator

My client wants qr-code based application using appcelerator for android and for iphone ? is it possible using appcelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen this google project?

http://code.google.com/p/tibar/

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's dead on for a good [iPhone lib](http://code.google.com/p/tibar/) but you will need separate one for the [android](https://github.com/mwaylabs/titanium-barcode).